# how to add and edit notes in egit

Tags: git, egit

Is there a way where we can add "Notes" to commits via Egit?
I don't seem to see a way to do that from EGit. The commit viewer shows the Notes if the commit has Notes on it, but not way to edit, append or add/remove.

Comment: You can file a feature request here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EGit&rep_platform=All&op_sys=All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet, it seems.

The [`jgit.api.AddNoteCommand`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/AddNoteCommand.java) API present in [JGit](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit) isn't used anywhere in [Egit](https://github.com/eclipse/egit).